# Solving $\dot{x}-\dot{y}+a(x-y)+b(x\dot{y}-y\dot{x})=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the following differential equation
$$\dot{x}-\dot{y}+a(x-y)+b(x\dot{y}-y\dot{x})=0\, .$$
What can we say about the functions $x(t)$, $y(t)$ that solve this equation? Can we find a relation between them, $f(x(t),y(t))=0$? For example, I tried substituting $w=x-y$; I obtained the folowing:
$$a\, w(t)\int \frac{1}{w(t)}dt=1-b \, x(t)\, .$$
I don't think that it is possible to do better. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $b \neq  0$, the equation can be written as the determinant

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc}{x'}+\frac{a}{b}&1-b x\\
{y'}+\frac{a}{b}&1-b y
\end{array}\right| = 0$$

Let $u = \binom{x}{y}$ and $v = \binom{1}{1}$, there is
a function $k(t)$ such that

$${u'} = -\frac{a}{b} v+k \left(v-b u\right)$$

This is now a simple first order linear system.

Comment: I forgot to assume $b \neq 0$. Just out of curiosity, because of your user name, are you in France ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is a confidential piece of information!

Comment: Thank you all! Is $k$ unknown? There is not a way to determine it, right?

Comment: $k$ can be any arbitrary continuous function, if you suppose for example that $x, y$ have continuous derivatives. Note that the point $(1/b, 1/b)$ should be studied separately because the equation vanishes at that point. I would be tempted to use $(\phi, \psi) = (1 - b x, 1 - b y)$ because the equation becomes simply $\binom{\phi}{\psi}^\prime = a \binom{1}{1} + k \binom{\phi}{\psi}$.

Answer (score 1):

*This may be a stupid answer.*

Why not to consider $y(x)$ leading to the differential equation
$$1-y'+a(x-y)+b(x{y'}-y)=0$$ that is to say
$$(bx-1)y'-(a+b)y+ax+1=0$$ which leads to $$y=x+c_1 (b x-1)^{\frac{a+b}{b}}$$